# How to use bot's name

Tags: azure, slack, botframework

so this is probably a really stupid question.

I made a bot, I put it on slack. It works great. Except, it doesn't use the name I gave it. Instead, it uses its AppId.

So, it does have a nice `@steve` username in slack, all msgs from it are using display name of `TEST_BOT`.

Can I make it write as Steve instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the step when you create a Bot User you can choose its username (it defaults to the AppName if you don't change it.

[image]

Comment: You can also change the name in your slack group if you change it where Lars indicates, then remove the bot and re-add it to your group.  it won't pick up the new name until then.

Comment: This is where I have given it the name Steve. It also shows as steve in the userlist. But the name it lists when it actually writes to private chat or channel, is TEST_BOT.

Comment: Did you try to re-register your credentials as suggested by the comment above?